# Replace only the numbers of a data frame column with roman numerals in R

Tags: r, replace

Hello i have created this example as reproducible column of my data frame.

```
sa<-c("Phase 1","Phase 2","Phase 1 | Phase 2","Phase 4")
```

What I want to do is replace all the numbers with the relative roman numeral and `|` with `\` without changing the word "Phase".

I try to isolate the numbers with:

```
phaa<-str_replace_all(sa, "[|]", "/ ")
saah<- strsplit(phaa, " ")
```

But then i cannot replace them properly

Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't particularly elegant, but as long as you aren't dealing with millions of entries, it should work well enough.  It makes use of the `as.roman` function in the `gtools` package.

```
library(gtools)
library(stringr)

sa<-c("Phase 1","Phase 2","Phase 1 | Phase 2","Phase 4")


sub_roman <- function(x){
  # identify any numbers (up to three digits)
  num <- as.numeric(unlist(str_extract_all(x, "\\d{1,3}")))
  for (i in seq_along(num)){
    # loop through the numbers and replace with the roman numeral
    x <- str_replace(x, "\\d{1,3}", as.character(as.roman(num[i])))
  }
  x
}

# Run the previously defined function over the vector.
sa <- 
  vapply(sa,
         sub_roman,
         character(1))

# replace the pipe with a slash.
sa <- str_replace_all(sa, "[|]", "/")
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know about `as.roman`.  That's cool. I just made a lookup.

Comment: I didn't know either.  I was considering what it would take to write one when it occurred to me that someone must have already done this.  Your answer is probably easier to implement if there aren't a lot of distinct numbers to convert.  This answer is _very_ generalized.

Comment: Yeah I just changed it to convert a sequence to roman so that you could just punch in a max and let it rip.  Thanks for making me aware of it, I'm sure it'll be useful one day!

Answer (score 3):

Capture the matches first

```
m <- gregexpr("(\\d)", sa)
```

Now using `sapply` apply `as.roman`

```
regmatches(sa, m) <- sapply(regmatches(sa, m), as.roman)
```

`sa` would now be:

```
sa
[1] "Phase I"            "Phase II"           "Phase I | Phase II"
[4] "Phase IV"
```

and finally use `gsub`

```
gsub(" \\| ", " / ", sa)
```

to obtain the desired output

```
[1] "Phase I"            "Phase II"           "Phase I / Phase II"
[4] "Phase IV"
```

Comment: Working great but @Benjamin answer matched better!

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try.

```
library(gsubfn)

new.sa <- gsubfn(pattern = '(\\d)',
                 replacement = as.list(setNames(as.character(as.roman(as.character(1:100))),as.character(1:100))),
                  x = sa)
new.sa
#[1] "Phase I"            "Phase II"           "Phase I | Phase II" "Phase IV"   
newer.sa <- gsub('[|]', '/', new.sa)
newer.sa
#[1] "Phase I"            "Phase II"           "Phase I / Phase II" "Phase IV"
```

Edit: Modified my answer after learning about as.roman() from Benjamin.

Comment: gsubfn can take a function (here represented as a formula) as 2nd arg so this variation is possible: `gsubfn("\\d+", ~ format(as.roman(x)), chartr("|", "/", sa))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck great to know, thanks!  Didn't like that you had to set a max limit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a hash table to map key value pairs and do string replacement.

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
library(hashmap)

sa <- c("Phase 1","Phase 2","Phase 1 | Phase 2","Phase 4")

temp <- data.table(stringr::str_replace_all(sa, "[|]", "/"))

temp <- temp %>%
  mutate(K1 = as.roman(1 : 4)) 

H <- hashmap(as.character(temp$K1), temp$V1)

H2 <- hashmap(H$keys(), H$values())

sa <- data.table(stringr::str_replace_all(H2$values(), "\\d", H2$keys()))
```